# How do I return all the desired dictionary values within an IF statement in python? (discord.py)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py

I am trying to iterate through all the values in this JSON dictionary to retrieve whenever a user(s) has the desired date set as their birthday. However, it will only return the first value.

This is the dictionary I am referencing:

```json
{
    "TARGETGUILD": {
        "USERID1": {
            "month": "09",
            "day": "10"
        },
        "USERID2": {
            "month": "09",
            "day": "10"
        }
    },
    "otherGUILD": {
        "USERID": {
            "month": "09",
            "day": "10"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```py
@commands.command(name="today", pass_context=True)
    async def today(self, ctx):
        today = datetime.today()
        today_month = today.strftime("%m")
        today_day = today.strftime("%d")
        guild_av = ctx.guild.icon_url

        with open('commands/birthday/birthdays.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        guild_data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
        birthday_dict = {"month": str(today_month), "day": str(today_day)}
        #length = len(guild_data)
        def find_birthday():
            for user in guild_data:
                if guild_data[user] == birthday_dict:
                    return ":tada: <@!" + str(user) + ">" + "\n"
                else:
                    return "`None`"

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f":calendar_spiral: {today_month}/{today_day}", description="**Today's Birthdays:**" + "\n" + "\n" + str(find_birthday()), color=discord.Color.greyple())
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild_av)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

In [this screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/42613630990f35d433cbb65ba4dd3b1f.png), you'll see it only will display the first user.

The "other" guild ID in the JSON, for example, will obviously work properly as there's only one user with a birthday as seen in [this screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/2c2788d51591421b4dca8f4e7f5bf5d6.png).

I've tried a couple of things, just to try and find out what my issue was.

For instance, when I do:

```py
def find_birthday():
    for user in guild_data:
        print(user)
```

It **DOES** print each user. So, that's what leads me to believe the issue is within my `if` statement. Whenever it sees the user's birthday matches, it only will print the first user that matches.

So, after looking through many threads... I just can't figure out how to make it list each person.

I apologize if this is a simple fix and/or easy solution that I'm missing (typically it always is). I have been stuck on it for a bit now, though. I'm still learning python. I'd appreciate it if anyone could steer me in the right direction.

**QUESTION**

> How do re-write this to allow it to return *multiple* values within an `if` statement?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You should consider using `yield` instead of `return`. You would then need to collect all the results from the generator before creating a string for the `description` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement exits the loop.  It just returns from the function `find_birthday()` immediately to return its result to the caller.